# Why can't I use `launchctl setenv` from `tmux`?

Tags: launchd, macports, tmux

If I'm running within `tmux` and I try to update an environment variable with `launchctl`, I see an error like this:

```
$ launchctl setenv GIT_SSH /opt/local/bin/ssh
Not privileged to set domain environment.
```

But it works fine from outside of `tmux`... any idea why that is, or if there's any sort of workaround?

Comment: How did you launch tmux? If from command line, launch tmux with sudo. If it is an app, `sudo open /path/to/tmux.app`

Comment: Try running tmux with sudo(`sudo tmux`) to give it admin privileges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running tmux as root is probably not a good idea. Someone has created a solution and explanation:

https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard

After configuring tmux to use reattach-to-user-namespace you can use launchctl setenv as yourself within tmux.

Comment: FWIW, I found that several years ago, and just didn't remember to answer my own question... But, yes, the `tmux-pasteboard` package from MacPorts does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it from a privileged account i.e.

```
$ sudo launchctl setenv GIT_SSH /opt/local/bin/ssh
```

And enter your password when prompted. This can only be done from an admin account by default.

Comment: It works fine w/o `sudo`, when I run it outside of `tmux`... I'll see if `sudo` is somehow necessary from within `tmux`, but that doesn't really seem like the sort of thing I'd want to include in my `~/.bashrc`...

Comment: Yes, running through `sudo` seems to work, but I still don't like it... For now, I'm just going to wrap the calls to this in my `~/.bashrc` in `if [[ -z "$TMUX"]] ; then ...`